# trying to use params on main route (/) of my meteor app

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to use params on my main route. But in fact the params are not set and they are used in the path :

```
Router.map(function funcClientRouterMap(){
    this.route('home', {
        path: '/:_redirect?',
        action: function funcClientRouterMapAction(){
            console.log(this.path, this.params);
        }
        })
});
```

now if i try manual redirection here is what i get :

```
Router.go('home'); // it redirects on / => ok
Router.go('home', {_redirect: test}); // this.path = /test, and this.params is empty
```

How can i use _redirect like a params and not a route ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have other routes defined in your router?

Comment: yes i have few routes, why ?

Answer (score 0):

`Router.go` accepts a path as its first argument (per the [docs](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/master/DOCS.md#changing-routes-programmatically)). So if you were trying to programmatically cause the same result as the user going to `/redirectMeSomewhere`, you just use:

```
Router.go('/redirectMeSomewhere');
```

And `this.params._redirect` should be `'redirectMeSomewhere'`.

Note that like @apendua implies, if you have other routes it could cause chaos to have a route defined as `/:anything`, because the other routes may never get triggered. If the above doesn't do the trick, try commenting out all your other routes to see if that changes anything.

Comment: you say it can be chaos, but in fact it can be, only if the params is the same content than one route, ma i wrong ?
actually this.params is always empty. I'll have to do a small project to test that feature only.

Comment: Try removing the `?` from your route? So just `path: '/:_redirect'`.